# How do I know if a user has already accepted/refused ios notifications with React-Native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I would like to display a custom screen asking the user to accept or refuse notifications on their iOS device. This screen should only be displayed if the user never registered or never accepted/refused notifications for the app.

Though, I don't seem to find a way to know if the user already registered or not. And I don't want to use any kind of async storage as this could be cleaned up by the user.

I found the method `PushNotificationIOS.checkPermissions` but this doesn't tell me if the user has registered yet.

I need a way to know if the user has "not yet registered", "accepted" or "declined".

If the user has not yet registered, I display the screen. If the user has accepted or declined the notifications, I don't display the screen.

Is there a way with React-Native to know this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "this returns the same thing whether the user has refused or hasn't yet accepted"? The return value of the function or the parameters returned in the callback? Also, posting some code in your question might help understand your problem

Comment: I don't have any code for something I don't know how to do :) I've updated my question to be clearer.

Comment: Do you use any library for implementing Push Notifications or native code only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ended up creating a bridge with Objective-C to access the authorizationStatus from javascript:

```
@implementation NotificationPermissions

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getAuthorizationStatus:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
    resolve(@(settings.authorizationStatus));
  }];
}
```

Then it can be used this way in javascript:

```
const authorizationStatus = await NotificationPermissions.getAuthorizationStatus();
```

`authorizationStatus` is a number between 0 and 3, based on [UNAuthorizationStatus](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unauthorizationstatus)

Answer (score -1):

This is how I'd check in native code.

```
import UserNotifications

  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings() { settings in
     switch settings.authorizationStatus {
     case .notDetermined:
        //Not asked
        break
     case .authorized:
        //Granted
        break
     case .denied:
        //Denied
        break
     default:
        //Provisional or unknown future value
        break
     }
  }
```

Comment: The OP clearly mentioned he is looking for a React Native solution. Not native.

Comment: @Pranay React Native supports native objective-c, swift, and Java modules. this is a valid solution to the question posed by OP

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I'm well aware it supports native objective-c and swift. If this answer were to be implemented, the OP needs to do a lot of setup and a platform check at runtime to load this module for iOS and then check for permissions. A ReactNative answer would have been better, like the other answer posted. Also, it wasn't me who downvoted if that's what you're after.

Comment: aight mate, no need to be so defensive I'm not "after" anything. You said OP clearly was looking for a React Native solution but this is IS a React Native solution, your criticism isn't helpful. Perhaps what you could say is that a pure javascript answer would be better, though that's really up to the OP to decide. Best regards, truly I meant no offense

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I didn't take any offense. I was just putting it out there in case you might think I downvoted because of my comment. Anyway, I meant to suggest that the OP might be looking for a pure ReactNative answer in JS